# Angular JS Click Event is not working

Tags: html, angularjs

I am for the first time trying to work on Angular JS . I designed a HTML form which contains hyperlink . Now i want to register a click event on the same hyperlink but it is not happening. I have added CDN reference for the angular JS at the end of Body and adding Javascript code in the head section of the HTML page.

Here is My Hyper Link markup..

```
<div ng-app="LoginApp" ng-controller="LoginController" class="top-big-link">
<a class="btn btn-link-1" href="" ng-click="Register()">Register</a>
<a class="btn btn-link-2" href="" ng-click="Login()">Login</a></div>
```

and here is my Angular JS Script in the Head Section ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('LoginApp', [])
    app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Register = function () {
       $scope.Message = "Button clicked."
    }
    <pre></pre>});
</script>
```

Also on checking the developer console of Chrome i am getting following error message ..

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]      http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=LoginApp&p1=Error%3…    ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A350)
```

Please help me to resolve this ..

Comment: Remove the  <pre></pre> element at the end of the function?

Comment: After removing <pre></pre>, if still seeing same error, either there is another error like this that we do not see in your post, or chrome is serving you the cached page. Make sure the cache is disabled: (on console, Network->Disable Cache) and the source code (js) is updated (on console, see it in Sources).

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your event handler: the error says "Syntax Error: Unexpected <". So your angular application did not even start, because the javascript code of your application is invalid.

This particular error, usually means your browser is trying to interpret some HTML code as javascript.

Start by removing the `<pre></pre>` from your controller code if that's not an artefact from copy pasting in stackoverflow.

If that does not work, it means that you are referencing another HTML file (most likely a 404 error) in a `<script src="..."></script>` somewhere in your code, or that you have a syntax error somewhere else.

Comment: I removed `<pre></pre>` still i am not able to see any click event ..Also i am not refrencing any other HTML file ..What could be possible cause ..?

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]      http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=LoginApp&p1=Error%3…    ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A350)`

Comment: These two error i am getting at launch time of the Page

Comment: All are getting opened..Can i get an alert message just like Jquery on click event ?If yes How ?

Comment: @Lara within your div somewhere put {{Message}}. You are setting Message on your scope on click, so you would see, after solving unrelated simple errors.

Comment: @Lara and besides, window.alert() is not jQuery related. You can use it here as well